# How do I set anchors for *ngFor elements in Angular2+?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, scroll, ngfor

There is an component with items shown with *ngFor. My goal is scrolling down to element with anchor #3.

The code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <button (click)="scroll(3)">scroll 2</button>
    <li *ngFor="let item of itemList; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">{{i}} {{item}}</li>
  `,
})
class HomeComponent {
    text = 'foo';
    testObject = {fieldFirst:'foo'};
    itemList = [
       //...
    ];

    scroll(el: HTMLElement) {
        el.scrollIntoView();
    }
}
```

There is an jsfiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/mr_blond97/8af0swqn/).

I can't figure out how do I set unchors for it?

Comment: did u try my suggested answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
    <button (click)="scroll('3')">scroll to 3</button>
    <li *ngFor="let item of itemList; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i" [attr.id]="i">{{i}} -->  {{item}}</li>
    <div #target>target</div>
```

and in **component**:

```
    scroll(id: string) {
      const el = document.getElementById(id)
        el.scrollIntoView();
   }
```

[Here is a sample fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/uzpcxhf8/)

Comment: @Brandon : The fiddle seems to be working fine. Can u please explain it better. it works event for `id="0"`

Comment: @Brandon : :D haha

Answer (score 1):

You can define some template variable on `li` elements.

```html
<button (click)="scroll(3)">scroll 2</button>
<li *ngFor="let item of itemList; let i = index" #elements>{{i}} {{item}}</li>
<div #target>target</div>
```

And retrieve these elements within your component as follows

`@ViewChildren('elements') listItems: QueryList<any>;`

And finally change your `scroll` method to this

```
scroll(id) {
    const el = this.listItems.toArray()[id].nativeElement;
    el.scrollIntoView();
}
```